# Вид получения данных в django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Имеется вот такой запрос:

```
stats = CompletedTask.objects.filter(
    Q(created_date__gt=serializer.data['begin_date'])
    & Q(created_date__lt=serializer.data['end_date'])
).values(shift_type_id=F('task__shift__type__id')).annotate(
    count=Count('task__shift__type__id')
)
```

Данные получаю в таком виде:

```
[
  {
    "shift_type_id": 4,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "shift_type_id": 5,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Какие есть способы получить данные в таком виде:

```
{4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Comment: Покажите код serializer и view.

Answer (score 3):

А что мешает преобразовать полученные данные?

```
# Данные в полученном формате
raw = [{"shift_type_id": 4, "count": 2},  {"shift_type_id": 5, "count": 1}]
# Преобразование к простому словарю
res = {el["shift_type_id"]: el["count"] for el in raw}
# Теперь res = {4: 2, 5: 1}
```